# How to replace values for a group of columns and a single row in a data frame?

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame as follows -

```
df <- cbind(c("a","b","c","d","e"),c(1,2,3,4,5),c(6,8,10,12,19))
colnames(df) <- c("c1","c2","c3")
```

I want to replace the values of 3rd row in column 2 and 3 to 7 and 9, respectively. I used the following code

```
df <- df%>%replace(list = df[,c(2:3)], values = c(7,9))
```

But it is not working. Could someone guide me please where I am wrong and how I can get the desired result?

Comment: first of all this is not a dataframe. For it to be a data.frame, you have to use the `data.frame` function in Base R or `cbind.data.frame`.

Answer (score 3):

We can pass the `list` as row/column indexing in a `matrix` and `cbind` creates a `matrix`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     replace(cbind(3, 2:3), c(7,9))
```

-output

```
df
    c1  c2  c3  
[1,] "a" "1" "6" 
[2,] "b" "2" "8" 
[3,] "c" "7" "9" 
[4,] "d" "4" "12"
[5,] "e" "5" "19"
```

Answer (score 2):

A R Base solution would be:

```
  df[3,2:3] <- c(7,9)
```